# Matching special characters with Regular Expression

Tags: regular-expression

Say it's very easy if I want to find something containing lower-case letters and numbers with

```
produce_text | grep -E '[0-9a-z]'
```

Brackets are useful to match a set of characters, but what about those that are somewhat special?
If I want to, using brackets, match *any* character **but** one of these: a closing bracket `]`, a dash (or hyphen) "-", both slashes `/` and `\`, a caret `^`, a colon `:`.
Will it look like this (I know this doesn't work)?

```
[^]-/\^:]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To match a literal `]` and a literal `-` in a [*Bracket Expression*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) you'll have to use them like this:

```
[^]/\^:-]
```

or, even better, since [some tools require the backslash to be escaped](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342501/matching-special-characters-with-regular-expression/342506?noredirect=1#comment606170_342506):

```
[^]/\\^:-]
```

that is
*The right-square-bracket ( ']' ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list  (after an initial '^', if any)*
and
*The hyphen-minus character shall be treated as itself if it occurs first (after an initial '^', if any) or last in the list*
hence
*If a bracket expression specifies both '-' and ']', the ']' shall be placed first (after the '^', if any) and the '-' last within the bracket expression.*
The rules for bracket expressions are the same for *ERE* and *BRE*.

Comment: I'd double the backslash to be on the safe side. It's needed with many `awk` implementations and `perl` for instance.

Comment: What about "From caret to closing bracket"? Like `[^-]]` (This one fails)?

Comment: @iBug - sure it fails as the right bracket has to be first if you want to match it literally. I'm not sure I get the point of that "range" that you mention as `^` is after `]` so `[^-]]` would not work even if both `^` and `]` were treated literally (just like `[b-a]`). Anyway, if you wanted to match from e.g. `;` to closing bracket you could use a range up to the char before `]` (which is backslash) and include `]` as first char in the bracket expression so e.g. `[];-\\]`.

Comment: @don_crissti What about `[[.^.]-[.-.]]`? I have a feeling that this would work. Let's assume that the ASCII code of `^` is before `-`.

Comment: Got a lazy solution for my question. Simply get everything special to collating characters, like `[^[.].][.-.]/\^:]`

Answer (score 7):

Strangely perhaps, you need to have a couple of characters in specific places. You must have `]` as the first character in a set, and `-` must be the last character in a set.

Here is an RE that meets your requirements: `[^]\^/-]`:

```
echo 'Hello[world]-[sun] ^^ 4/5 or 3\4' | grep -Eo '[^]\^/-]' | xargs
H e l l o [ w o r l d [ s u n 4 5 o r 3 4
```

Comment: It's not really strange, it's just necessary to avoid ambiguity

Comment: The second `[` character doesn't belong there; the OP doesn't want to exclude it.

Comment: @Scott well spotted, thank you. Answer updated.