# How do I use sed to remove all but certain punctuation globally?

Tags: text-processing, sed, text-formatting

How can I remove all punctuation from a file using sed, with the exception of certain characters? Specifically, I want to keep these characters:

```
@-_$%
```

I am currently using this to remove all punctuation, but I am not sure how to modify it to keep those characters:

```
cat input.txt | sed -e "s/[[:punct:]]\+//g" > output.txt
```

Alternatively, how can I remove only certain punctuation? Like:

```
.!?,'/\"()[]^*
```

Comment: Use a bracket expression `[...]` and keep in mind that `]` [has to be first and `-` last in that list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342501) e.g. `sed 's/[].!?,'\''/\\"()[^*]//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

Sample file contents:

```
.!?,'/\"()[]^* @-$%
.!?,'/\"()[]^* @ sdfsd %
as,,d//asd a?sd %%   --@_ _asdasdad$
sdfsdf %''%!% 2 + 2 = (?)
```

---

```
sed '/[[:punct:]]*/{ s/[^[:alnum:][:space:]@_$%-]//g}' file
```

---

The output:

```
 @-$%
 @ sdfsd %
asdasd asd %%   --@_ _asdasdad$
sdfsdf %%% 2  2
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove only the characters:

```
.!?,'/\"()[]^*
```

Use a character class like so:

```
[][.!?,'/\\"()^*]
```

Note that the `]` character must be *first.*  Also, the `^` cannot be first since that would mean something entirely different.  And the backslash is escaped.

Now, to actually *use* this character class, you have to get it to Sed.  One way to do that is to put

```
s/[][.!?,'/\\"()^*]\+//g
```

in a file, and call it with `sed -f scriptfile input.txt`.

Another (trickier) way is to use shell quoting:

```
sed -e 's/[][.!?,'\''/\\"()^*]\+//g' input.txt
```

---

For the other part of your question, there is no way to match all characters in a character class *except* certain listed characters.

You can, however, match all NON-punctuation characters like so:

```
[^[:punct:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that very easily using `perl6`:

```
perl6 -pe 's:g/<:punct-[-@_%]>+//' file
```

- `<:punct-[-@_%]>` will match any punctuation character, except `-@_%`.
- `:g` is the `global` switch (like s/foo/bar/`g` in perl5 or sed)

To be allow comparison between answers (and also because I'm lazy), I'll reuse @RomanPerekhrest's sample input:

```
.!?,'/\"()[]^* @-$%
.!?,'/\"()[]^* @ sdfsd %
as,,d//asd a?sd %%   --@_ _asdasdad$
sdfsdf %''%!% 2 + 2 = (?)
```

So this line:

```
perl6 -pe 's:g/<:punct-[-@_%]+[^]>+//' file
```

Gives:

```
^ @-$%
^ @ sdfsd %
asdasd asd %%   --@_ _asdasdad$
sdfsdf %%% 2 + 2 =
```

Note that it differs from the answer given by @RomanPerekhrest. If you consider that `^`, `=` or `+` should be included too, then you can use the following line:

```
perl6 -pe 's:g/<:punct-[-@_%]+[^+=]>+//' file
```

The output will be the same:

```
 @-$%
 @ sdfsd %
asdasd asd %%   --@_ _asdasdad$
sdfsdf %%% 2  2
```